# How can I set the Toast Notification to be in the center of the screen?

Tags: powershell

I need a way to center the current window on the screen.

Also I have been working different resolution. The question is what should I do to make it work on any other resolution like 1024x768 or any others?

PowerShell script:

```
Submit-BTNotification -Content (
  New-BTContent -Scenario IncomingCall `
                -Audio (New-BTAudio -Silent) `
                -Visual (
                  New-BTVisual -BindingGeneric (
                    New-BTBinding -Children (New-BTText -Content '......message......') `
                                  -HeroImage (
                                    New-BTImage -Source C:\Logo\Autopilot.jpg -HeroImage
                                  )`
                                  -AppLogoOverride (
                                    New-BTImage -AppLogoOverride -Crop Circle -Source C:\Logo\AutopilotAppLogo.jpg
                                  )
                  )  
                ) 
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this is *not* possible: for consistency, toast notifications *always* "appear in the lower right of the user’s screen", per [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/toast-ux-guidance).

Here's a [forum thread](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/how-to-change-toast-notifications-position/98d3efba-dd78-4a53-b4b4-9ba36b28c794?page=2) discussing the inability to control the on-screen placement.

If centering on the screen is a must, you'll have to implement your notification via a *custom GUI* (you could still integrate with the toast notifications system by accompanying it with a toast notification that doesn't pop up and shows only in Notification Center, via `-SuppressPopup` if you're using the [`BurntToast`](https://github.com/Windos/BurntToast) modules).